# Using word-wrap: break-word on two consecutive long words

Tags: css, word-wrap

When using word-wrap: break-word on a div with two consecutive long words, the second word that is broken off starts on a new line, as such:

```
IAmALongW
ord
IAmAlsoAL
longword
```

Is there any way to prevent this in css, to get the following?

```
IAmALongW
ord IAmAl
soALongwo
rd
```

Without reverting to word-break: break-all, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container{
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>thisisaverylongword anotherverylongword</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `white-space: pre;` should do it, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
&nbsp;
```

in between words rather than just a space can help prevent the element forcing a break where you don't want one also. This helps when you do not want to leave one small word on a line on its own for instance.